# Dock any application to edge of screen

Tags: windows-10, desktop

Is there any way to dock a window to the edge of the screen in Windows 10 in a way that blocks any other window to cover that area. Essentially like the taskbar, but I want to choose the window to dock.

I have tried googling for a tool, but all hits give me the built-in Window snap feature.

edit:
Preferably, the normal Windows snap feature would still work, but only use the area occupied by Paint in the picture.

edit:
The term to do this might be "appbar".

[image]

Comment: If you were a programmer, you could write this app in your sleep. What you need is a program that will apply the HWND_TOPMOST attribute to the main window in the app you want to do this to.  Windows already snaps stuff to the edge of a screen.  [Try this app](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Other-Desktop-Enhancements/Window-TopMost-Control.shtml)

Comment: Turns out that I am :) . I will try something with AutoIt. Wrt the snap feature in Windows, I would like it to operate on the area that is left, so that I still can split windows over it easily (question updated). I'll see what happens with HWND_TOPMOST.

Comment: Have you tried holding the "Windows" key and pressing the "right arrow" key, while the Notepad program is selected, after that shrink it to the right to desired width, open/select Paint and hold the "Windows" key, press the "Left arrow" key and you should have the desired output.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas It turns on that setting a window on top does not dock it. Maybe I can find some other Windows API.

Comment: @Leshy That works well if I only need it once. However, for every new window I open, I have to press Win+Left. Also, preferably, I would like to be able to snap other applications left and right while the docked window is sitting on the side, never being covered.

Comment: No.. I assumed that 'snapping' to the sides was good enough with the topmost attribute.  If not.. this sounds like a fun application to write. :) good luck